# Running with the Apple Watch 3 non-cellular. Can I leave my phone behind?

Tags: apple-watch

The LTE version of the Apple Watch Series 3 is not available in my country. Can I use the non-cellular version of the watch for tracking my runs while leaving my phone at home? Would this compromise the accuracy of the tracking?

I know that the watch has GPS, but how would it affect the apps if there is no data connectivity while tracking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I use the non-cellular version of the watch for tracking my runs
>   while leaving my phone at home?

Yes.  The [Apple Watch Series 2](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP746?locale=en_US) doesn't need to be paired to an iPhone to utilize GPS tracking because it's built in.

From a [MacWorld](https://www.macworld.com/article/3120333/iphone-ipad/early-apple-watch-series-2-reviews-praise-the-gps-and-brighter-screen.html) article on the AWS2 and the GPS functionality:

> ...loved how the Series 2 and iPhone intelligently passed off route
>   tracking duties. “Apple Watch just seems to know when it’s out of
>   communication distance from its paired iPhone, and it gets a GPS
>   signal without you telling it to. And if I do have my phone with me,
>   the Workout app will let the iPhone do the GPS because it’s the
>   bigger-batteried device.”

And from [Runners World](https://www.runnersworld.com/gear-check/review-apple-watch-series-2-is-a-solid-option) on the GPS functionality and the accuracy:

> The biggest update for the Apple Watch 2 is a new focus on fitness and
>   the integration of GPS into the watch itself. The first version
>   off-loaded that work to your phone, but not all runners like to carry
>   a phone when working out. Now they don’t have to. In our testing,
>   we’ve found the GPS accuracy to be on par with our sport-specific
>   watches